# Android Firebase notification clicks not working when app is in background

Tags: android

Getting message type "data" only in response. but app not calling onMessageReceive method on time of receiving notification.

```
{
    "data" : {
      "body" : "Body of the notification example",
      "action_id" : "4"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: which phone you are using for testing?

Comment: please post any relevant code to this question, look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here https://stackoverflow.com/tour for more info

Answer (score 0):

Have you done something like this? This is for handling data message.

```
public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
}

private void showNotification(Map<String, String> data) {
    String title = data.get("title");
    String body = data.get("body");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "ChannelID";

    if(notificationManager != null) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NotificationManager",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

              notificationChannel.setDescription("My Channel");
              notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.supportop_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);

        // Handle notification click
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Activity.class), 0);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);

        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
}
```